# Why does the \onslide command in beamer reset the dimension \hfuzz?

Tags: beamer, overlays, badness

I needed to set `\hfuzz` to a very large value for a beamer frame which had a substantial number of slides overlayed. Then I found (the hard way) that I have to issue `\hfuzz\maxdimen`
after each of the `\onslide` commands.

---

(Actually, I do not need them *that* big. I am putting in some codes which show overfull hboxes of varying amount (10.0pt to 50.0pt or some such), even after changing the font size. But they do not cross the frame width. Instead of putting varying amounts of `\hfuzz` for each case, I decided to use `\maxdimen` rather blindly. I simply wanted to get rid of the warning messages for which I seem to have an allergy.)

---

The following is a very simplified version of the above-mentioned scenario.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

% 1
\hfuzz\maxdimen
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  % 2
  % \hfuzz\maxdimen
  \begin{overprint}
    % 3
    \showthe\hfuzz
    % \hfuzz\maxdimen
    \onslide<+>
    \showthe\hfuzz
    % 4
    % \hfuzz\maxdimen
    \verb@ A long long long long long long long long text to be displayed@
    \onslide<+>
    \showthe\hfuzz
    % 5
    % \hfuzz\maxdimen
    \verb@ Another long long long long long long long long text to be displayed@
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Indeed, in the above code, only %4 and %5 `\hfuzz`, after each `\onslide` command suppress the overfull hbox message.

A little more investigation, inserting `\showthe\hfuzz` at three places, evidence
that `\hfuzz` gets reset to the default 0.5pt value after the `\onslide` command.

> ```
> > 16383.99998pt.
> l.3     \showthe\hfuzz
>
> ? 
> > 0.5pt.
> l.6     \showthe\hfuzz
> ...............                      
> ? 
> > 0.5pt.
> l.11     \showthe\hfuzz
> ```

- Why did the implementer decide to reset `\hfuzz` after every `\onslide`?
- And
  is there any way I can set  `\hfuzz` to `\maxdimen` for a particular  frame or a
  group of frames
  containing overlays?

Comment: without looking at the source, it probably uses `\sloppy` which sets `\hfuzz` to that value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any particular reason to use `\sloppy` inside an overlay slide? Are not they just like other *regular* slides?

Comment: My rule of thumb is: When I get an overfull box, I check where it is, and if it _looks_ fine, I don't care that it is not correct according to LaTeX.

Comment: @tohecz Yes, as I said, I have an aversion for the warning messages. I always find a way to shut them up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably beamer uses `\sloppy` as that sets `\hfuzz` to 0.5pt.

It is hard to imagine why you need boxes so overfull but anyway, for any document,
if you put

```
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\newdimen\hfuzz
```

in the preamble then the primitive `\hfuzz` will be set to maxdimen and then not be accessible, any code that sets the the dimen `\hfuzz` will just set the dimen register and not affect the log output.

Comment: No, actually, I do not need them *that* big. I am putting in some codes which show overfull hboxes of varying amount, but do not cross the frame width. Instead of putting varying amount of `\hfuzz` for each case, I decided to use `\maxdimen` rather blindly. Thanks anyway for your answer.