# Overfull \hbox When Using Overprint in Beamer

Tags: beamer

Encountered a curiosity and hope to learn something from it.

In the following MWE, the first slide is created without any fuss, but the second slide, which uses the `overprint` feature, results in two `Overfull \hbox...` messages in the log:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{First Slide}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{jpgimage1}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}\frametitle{Second Slide}
    \begin{overprint}
        \includegraphics<1>[width=0.1\linewidth]{jpgimage1}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=0.1\linewidth]{jpgimage2}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've made the images in the second slide really small, in an attempt to avoid said `Overfull...` squawks, but with no success in doing so.  Feel free to use any images you may have on hand, I think you'll get the same result I did.

Why does this happen?  FYI, I found a "workaround" in David Carlisle's answer to this question: [Why does the \onslide command in beamer reset the dimension \hfuzz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211678/why-does-the-onslide-command-in-beamer-reset-the-dimension-hfuzz), but still don't understand what is really going on.

Any enlightenment will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the overfull box by specifying a width wide enough to accommodate your image by using `\begin{overprint}[0.11\linewidth]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{First Slide}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}\frametitle{Second Slide}
    \begin{overprint}[0.11\linewidth]
        \includegraphics<1>[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, @samcarter...your addition clears up the subject `Overfull \hbox...` squawk even when I replace same with `[0\linewidth]`.

Comment: Also, @samcarter, is your solution preferable to adding a `\hfuzz=maxdimen` line to the code prior to the `\begin{overprint}` command?

Comment: @Digger There is no general answer which is better - this depends on the situation and your frame layout. Specifying the optional argument of the `overprint` has the advantage that this width is reserved and in case you have some elements right of the overprint they won't jump between slides. As for the `\hfuzz` approach, this effectively suppresses the warning, you should make sure that you understand where the warning is coming from and that it does not cause any problems.