# How to ignore bad boxes with ieeecolor?

Tags: boxes, ieeetran, warnings, ieeecolor

I am using `ieeecolor.cls` for the first time - get it from https://www.embs.org/tmi/authors-instructions/, namely, https://www.embs.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/TMI-Template-LaTeX-2020.zip

What annoys me is that the default settings as recommended by the journal result in overfull and underfull boxes:

```
Overfull \hbox (109.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (162.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \vbox (21.77283pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

I have tried to fix them, but I don't really see where any maximum width is defined, so I have no idea why any of the elements in the header exceed these widths. Clearly, they do not exceed the standard page margins by 160 points. Then I have tried to suppress them, without luck.

What else can I try?

```latex
\vfuzz=\maxdimen
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\hbadness=100000
\vbadness=100000

\documentclass[print]{ieeecolor}

%\usepackage{tmi}
\def\logoname{LOGO-tmi-web}
\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0.541,0.855}
\setlength{\firstpagerule}{26.5pc}
\setlength{\logowidth}{16.5pc}
\def\journalname{IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Long title: foo bar yada yada foo bar yes thank you that's enough.}
\markboth{\journalname}{Short title}
\author{Author one, two, three, four. \thanks{\lipsum[1]}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: breaks my heart to suggest this but the class has too many features:(  stick `\hfuzz=\maxdimen` before `\maketitle` and set it back to .1pt after the first page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you! it's important to put `\hfuzz` *after* `\documentclass` - I had it *before*, where it is not working. (I still don't get why, because `ieeecolor.cls` does not contain the terms `hfuzz`, `LoadClass`, `usepackage`, `RequirePackage` [except with the `color` package], ...).

Comment: Ah, that's due to the use of `\sloppy`... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211680/30810

Comment: hfuzz is a tex primitive it just silences the warning so it does not appear in the class file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50830/do-i-have-to-care-about-bad-boxes/50850#50850  (oh I see, you mean it being reset yes sloppy and fussy) or in this case you want really really gross, not just sloppy:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "... and set it back to .1pt **after the first page**". Are there any triggers that I can use, such as `\AtBeginDocument`? I can do `\pretocmd{\maketitle}` for the first part, but resetting `\hfuzz` to previous values cannot be done using `\apptocmd{\maketitle}` as that appears to be too early. I could use `atbegshi`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me try myself ;) it seems it must go on the second page, and `\AtBeginShipout{\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{1}{\hfuzz=\oldhfuzz\vfuzz=\oldvfuzz}{}}` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in part on @DavidCarlisle's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562794/how-to-ignore-overfull-boxes-with-ieeecolor?noredirect=1#comment1418768_562794), this answer works for me in the preamble. This has three parts: the first turns off most box warnings on the page where `\maketitle` is issued. The next block sets the box warning values back to the previous values at the end of the page where `\maketitle` is issued.

The third block is only required for the `journal` option, I believe. It replaces a `\vbox` from the head code by `\parbox[c][15pt][c]`, maintaining all spacing and still removing the

> Overfull \vbox (5.0pt too high)

warnings on later pages.

```
% Suppress other "Underfull hbox", "Overfull *box" just before \maketitle
\pretocmd{\maketitle}{%
    \newcounter{titlepage}\setcounter{titlepage}{\value{page}}%
    \newcount\oldhbadness\oldhbadness=\hbadness\hbadness=10000
    \newdimen\oldhfuzz\oldhfuzz=\hfuzz\hfuzz=162pt%
    \newdimen\oldvfuzz\oldvfuzz=\vfuzz\vfuzz=22pt%
}{}{Error.}

% Re-enable on following page
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{page}}{\value{titlepage}}{%
        \global\hbadness=\oldhbadness%
        \global\hfuzz=\oldhfuzz%
        \global\vfuzz=\oldvfuzz%
    }{}%
}

% Fix "Overfull \vbox (5.0pt too high)" on later pages
\patchcmd{\@evenhead}{%
    \vbox{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
}{%
    \parbox[c][15pt][c]{\textwidth}{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
}{}{Error.}
\patchcmd{\@oddhead}{%
    \vbox{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
}{%
    \parbox[c][15pt][c]{\textwidth}{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
}{}{Error.}
\makeatother
```

This full MWE demonstrates the effect of suppressing warning, and generates test warnings which show that warnings are suppressed only on the title page:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{tmi}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifgeneratetestwarnings
\generatetestwarningstrue

\newif\ifsuppressclasswarnings
\suppressclasswarningstrue
\ifsuppressclasswarnings
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{atbegshi}

    % Suppress other "Underfull hbox", "Overfull *box" just before \maketitle
    \pretocmd{\maketitle}{%
        \newcounter{titlepage}\setcounter{titlepage}{\value{page}}%
        \newcount\oldhbadness\oldhbadness=\hbadness\hbadness=10000
        \newdimen\oldhfuzz\oldhfuzz=\hfuzz\hfuzz=162pt%
        \newdimen\oldvfuzz\oldvfuzz=\vfuzz\vfuzz=22pt%
    }{}{Error.}

    % Re-enable on following page
    \AtBeginShipout{%
        \ifnumequal{\value{page}}{\value{titlepage}}{%
            \global\hbadness=\oldhbadness%
            \global\hfuzz=\oldhfuzz%
            \global\vfuzz=\oldvfuzz%
        }{}%
    }

    % Fix "Overfull \vbox (5.0pt too high)" on later pages
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@evenhead}{%
        \vbox{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
    }{%
        \parbox[c][15pt][c]{\textwidth}{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
    }{}{Error.}
    \patchcmd{\@oddhead}{%
        \vbox{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
    }{%
        \parbox[c][15pt][c]{\textwidth}{\color{subsectioncolor}\hrule height1pt width43pc depth0pt}%
    }{}{Error.}
    \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author \thanks{Thanks.}}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-17]

\ifgeneratetestwarnings
    This underfuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuull hbox should be a warning.

    This \mbox{overfuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuull} hbox, too (4.43956pt).

    \parbox[c][2in][s]{4cm}{This underfull vbox, too.}

    This overfull vbox, too (2.0pt):\newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][690pt]{\textwidth}\end{minipage}
\fi

\end{document}
```